# Which hook to add custom data In New Order Admin Woocommerce email

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, coupon

In WooCommerce, How and where I can apply some code for New Order Email notification, where I should get the Applied Coupon Code display.

In the template for New Order Email notification I have @hooked `WC_Emails::order_details()` that shows the order details table…

Also is `WC_Email::order_details()` the exact hook which I am searching for to update coupon code in New order mail to admin?

I am loosed, any help will be really appreciated…

Answer (score 4):

The hook that you are searching is **`woocommerce_email_order_details`** action hook that can be used this way:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_order_details', 'action_email_order_details', 10, 4 );
    function action_email_order_details( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ) {
     if( $sent_to_admin ): // For admin emails notification

     // Your code goes HERE

     endif;
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

---

In your function you can use any of the 4 arguments from the hook like `$order` the `WC_Order` object.

You can use the `WC_Abstract_Order` method [`get_used_coupons()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Abstract_Order.html#_get_used_coupons) that will give you an array of coupons codes used in the order, like:

```
// Get the array of coupons codes
$coupon_codes = $order->get_used_coupons();

// Convert and display the array in a coma separated string:
echo 'Coupon codes: ' . implode( ', ', $coupon_codes );
```